# sql server 2008 r2 can connect with connection manager but noway else

Tags: sql-server-2008, connection

I have installed (3 times on 3 machines) sql server 2008 r2 can connect with connection manager but other program cannot connect.
I can connect to remote sql servers with heidisql or with my dbcontroles in visal studio or embarcadero delphi xe2. But non of those can connect to te sql server whlie the connection-manager can.
What settings may be involved?
-My firewall is open for SQL server.
-I use the same port numer everywhere

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you connecting to a default instance, or a named instance?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what connection manager is, but I'm assuming you mean SQL Server Management Studio. If I'm not mistaken, SQL Server since SQL Server 2005 installs with only the Shared Memory protocol enabled and all network protocols disabled. You're able to connect via SSMS on the server to the SQL Server database engine instance on the server because it's connecting via Shared Memory protocol. In order to connect to it from another host on the network you'll need to enable the appropriate network protocol; Named Pipes or TCP/IP, whichever suits your need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187892.aspx